# Asociar un evento para campos input - Convertir a mayúsculas - Javascript

Tags: javascript, entrada

Imaginaros que tengo 20 campos `<input text>` a rellenar en un formulario, y quiero convertir automáticamente el contenido de estos campos a mayúsculas. 
¿Tendría que poner en cada `<input text>` del `HTML` la siguiente sentencia o hay una forma global de encapsular todos los inputs?

```
onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes hacerlo con todos. Debes obtenerlos y posteriormente recorrerlos añadiendo los llamados manejadores de eventos. Introduce lo siguiente en una etiqueta `<script>`:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var input = inputs[i];
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Tengo una función llamada myOnLoad en un .js en la cual llamo a las funciones que quiero que se realicen al cargar la página. Ese myOnLoad lo llamo en el HTML en el <body>, ¿es buena práctica o es necesario casi siempre utilizar "window.onload = ....."

Comment: Depende. Tienes escrito `window.onload = myOnLoad;`? Si es asi, aisla en una funcion el codigo que te he proporcionado y tan solo llama a esta nueva funcion desde `myOnLoad`. El codigo JS llamalo siempre al final del `body`, justo antes de `</body>`. Llamalo en el `<head>` en caso de ser estrictamente necesario, pero normalmente con colocarlo al final del body no tendras problemas.

Comment: Me funciona correctamente transformándolo en mi código, sólo era una duda que tengo de buena práctica.

Comment: @omaza1990 La idea es hacer `window.onload = funcion`, y en `funcion` llamar a todo lo que quieras ejecutar cuando la pagina cargue, tal como tu tienes hecho. Una mala practica seria hacer `window.onload =` varias veces.

Comment: Perfecto duda resuelta. Tengo sólo un único "window.onload", dentro del cual las funciones que quiero que se ejecuten.